# How to create a pandas object from array with unknown rank?

Tags: pandas, multidimensional-array, dataframe

Given any Numpy array, I want to create the best matching pandas data structure out of `pd.Series`, `pd.DataFrame`, etc. Is there a built-in function for this? I guess so but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: who might know better than you what is best matching __for you__? for example between: `pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3,4,11]))` and `pd.Series(np.array([1,2,3,4,11]))`

Comment: @MaxU Okay, let's define it to be the least-dimensional container that works. In your example, that would be series.

Comment: I think you can use `numpy.ndarray.ndim` in order to identify the number of dimensions and then use: 1 - `pd.Series()`, 2 - `pd.DataFrame()`, 3 - `pd.Panel()`. I'm not aware of any pandas constructor that might do it for you automatically. You may also want to look at [xray](http://xray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data-structures.html#dataset)